# Are there any modern browser/machine that not accept class 1 SSL certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate

I'm considering to buy a SSL certificate from external Certificate Authority to my web service which does not involve e-commerce.
So I was planning to request the simplest class 1 cert to eliminate the scary warning message

*(eg. When building https connection to a site with self-signed certificate. The chrome warns)*.

> Your connection is not private
>
> Attackers might be trying to steal your information from localhost (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards).
>
> Back to safetyHide advanced
> This server could not prove that it is localhost; its security certificate is not trusted by your computer's operating system. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.
>
> Proceed to localhost (unsafe)
>
> NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Through google-ing, I saw some questions
( [Class 1 Certificate not accepted on android](https://forum.startcom.org/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=15750),
[StartSSL class 1 certificate not accepted by browser (Weblogic 10.0.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879370/startssl-class-1-certificate-not-accepted-by-browser-weblogic-10-0-1) )
saying that their class 1 cert not accepted by some browser/environment. Although their cause seems just faulty settings.

Besides, there is an announce that Mozilla is planning to reject certificate with insecure algorithm based signature start from January 1, 2017. ( [Phasing Out Certificates with SHA-1 based Signature Algorithms](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2014/09/23/phasing-out-certificates-with-sha-1-based-signature-algorithms/) )

That is, there exists an announce to reject a certificate because the based algorithm is insecure. And I want to know if there is some browser/environment that reject certificate because the investigation level is too low?

In short, I want to make sure:
**Is there any modern browser/machine that does not accept class 1 certificate and shows scary message to the user?**

Comment: Are you talking of CACert here?

Comment: @vautee yes. such as web server SSL/TLS certificate provided by [StartSSL](https://www.startssl.com/)

Comment: As far as I know, StartSSL certificates (even the free ones) are good on any modern browser and won't show scary messages to the user.